# Getting SourceMap position not found for trace with karma-typescript

Tags: karma-runner, source-maps, karma-mocha, karma-typescript

**Getting SourceMap position not found for trace**. I am trying to build a unit test framework using **typescript, mocha, karma, and karma-typescript** and getting the following issue.
I tried using **karma-sourcemap-loader** but still, there is no luck. Can anyone please guide me on what am I missing here?

**karma-typescript** should be able to handle these source map things by themself in between multiple transformations.

```
Fetching /Users/test/sourcecode/test-web-ui/node_modules/karma-typescript/dist/client/commonjs.js
17 08 2021 23:47:06.959:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/raukumar/sourcecode/test-web-ui/node_modules/karma-typescript/dist/client/commonjs.js
17 08 2021 23:47:07.357:WARN [reporter]: SourceMap position not found for trace: Uncaught Error: Can't find @react/react-spectrum/Button [undefined] (required by /Users/test/sourcecode/elements-web-ui/src/editors/doc/stage/actions/StageActionsView.tsx)
at http://localhost:9882/base/node_modules/karma-typescript/dist/client/commonjs.js?f5014f1e344ba3e2f0d92afe67b92f3001c46c90:13:17
```

I tried this solution [SourceMap position not found for trace: AssertionError (Karma-Typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519696/sourcemap-position-not-found-for-trace-assertionerror-karma-typescript) but after this, I am getting some different issues.

```
 Uncaught Error: Can't find @react/react-spectrum/Button [undefined] (required by /Users/test/sourcecode/src/somefile.tsx
```

**Karma.conf**

```js
module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({
        // basePath: '',
        //configFile: join(__dirname, "testing.tsconfig.json"),
        plugins: ['karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-mocha', 'karma-typescript', 'karma-webpack','karma-mocha-reporter','karma-sourcemap-loader'],
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'karma-typescript'],
        preprocessors: {
            "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript","sourcemap"],
            "**/*.tsx": ["karma-typescript","sourcemap"], // *.tsx for React Jsx
            '**/*.js': ["sourcemap"]
            //"src/**/*.js": ["babel"]
        },
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: false,
        color:true,
        reporters: ["mocha", "karma-typescript"],
        //files: [{ pattern: "src/**/*.ts" }, {pattern: "src/**/*.tsx" }, {pattern: "src/**/*.js"}],
        files: [{ pattern: "src/**/!(*.spec).?(ts|tsx)" }, { pattern: "src/**/!(*.integration.spec).?(ts|tsx)" } ],
        //webpack: webpackConfig,
        karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            // Allow tests to run even when there are compiler errors
            stopOnFailure: true,
            bundlerOptions: {
                acornOptions: {
                    ecmaVersion: 8,
                  },
                transforms: [
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
                    require("karma-typescript-es6-transform")({
                        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
                        //presets: [require("@babel/preset-env",{ "useBuiltIns": "entry"})],
                        //plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-spread'],
                        presets: [
                            ["env", {
                             targets: {
                              browsers: ["last 2 Chrome versions"]
                             }
                            }]
                           ]
                    })
                ]
            },
            compilerOptions: {
                target: "ES2017",
                lib: ['DOM', 'ES2015', 'ES2017'],
                module: "CommonJS",

                // Remove incompatible options
                //incremental: false
            },
            tsconfig: "testing.tsconfig.json"
        }
    });
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "incremental": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true
      },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts","src/**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```